# Span elements in one line does not wrap within Bootstrap container in Chrome Browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have an odd problem.  Have several  elements in one line within a 250px wide Bootstrap container.  I want the elements to wrap and fill within the 250px column.  THIS USED TO WORK IN CHROME JUST A FEW MONTHS AGO, BUT NOT ANY MORE!  Works in IE, Safari, Edge.  What has happened in Chrome and how can I get this to work in Chrome again with minimal changes?

The code is below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>      
    <style>
    .tag {
       height: 26px;
       width: auto;
       border: 1px solid #CAD8F3;
       background-color: #DEE7F8;
       border-radius: 6px;
       line-height: 24px;
       text-align: center;
       display:inline-block;
       padding-right: 10px;
       padding-left: 10px;
       font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
       font-size: 100%;
       color: #555555;
       margin-bottom: 3px;
       cursor: pointer;
     }
     .tag:hover {
         background-color:#b2ccf7;  
         border: 1px solid #5b7596;
     }
    </style>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- CODE STYLE -->
    <!-- OBJECTIVE IS TO WRAP SPAN ITEMS WITHIN THE 250PX COLUMN WIDTH -->
    <!-- WORKS IN IE, SAFARI, EDGE, BUT NOT IN CHROME -->
    <!-- *** USED TO WORK IN CHROME *** A FEW MONTHS AGO, BUT NOW GET A LONG TAGLIST THAT FALLS OFF THE PAGE, DOES NOT WRAP WITHIN THE 250PX COLUMN -->
    <div id="side" style="width: 250px; margin-left: 50px; margin-top: 0px;">
        <div class="container" id="custom_tags_show" style="display:block;">
            <span id="tags">
                <!-- BELOW IS GENERATED BY SQL COMMAND, WOULD LIKE TO KEEP THIS FORMAT IF POSSIBLE, TO AVOID CHANGING CODE IN MANY PLACES -->
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">jfk&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(3)</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">food&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(3)</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">super-natural&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(3)</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">booboo&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">e&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">new&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">asdf&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">huno&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">two&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">dsfg&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">time&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">growth&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">contradictions&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">archaeology&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">family&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">hotmail&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">shocking&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">baby&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">big&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">dd&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">ff&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">four&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">g&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">job&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span>&nbsp;<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">sss&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span>&nbsp;                    
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <!-- THIS WORKS IN CHROME TO WRAP THE SPAN OBJECTS, BUT THIS IS NOT WHAT IS GENERATED BY THE SQL COMMAND AND WOULD RATHER NOT HAVE TO CHANGE CODE TO ACCOMODATE THIS -->
    <div id="side" style="width: 250px; margin-left: 50px; margin-top: 0px;">
        <div class="container" id="custom_tags_show" style="display:block;">
            <span id="tags">
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">jfk&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(3)</span></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">food&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(3)</span></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">super-natural&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(3)</span></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">booboo&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">e&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">new&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">asdf&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">huno&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">two&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">dsfg&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">time&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">growth&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">contradictions&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">archaeology&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">family&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">hotmail&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">shocking&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">baby&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">big&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">dd&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">ff&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">four&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">g&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">job&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">sss&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span>&nbsp;                    
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a flexbox for the same. More Information here:-

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

Add this snippet to your code:-

```
#tags{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the wrapping worked in Chrome when I removed the &nbsp at the end of each tag element:

ORIGINAL TAG ELEMENT:

```
<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">jfk&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(3)</span></span>&nbsp;
```

TAG ELEMENT WITH `&nbsp;` removed from the end

```
<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">jfk&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(3)</span></span>
```

THE FULL LONG LINE OF TAGS THAT WORKS WITH CHROME WRAPPING IS THEN:

```
<span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">jfk&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(3)</span></span><span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">food&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(3)</span></span><span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">super-natural&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(3)</span></span><span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">booboo&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span><span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">e&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span><span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">new&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span><span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">asdf&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span><span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">huno&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span><span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">two&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span><span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span><span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">dsfg&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span><span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">time&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span><span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">growth&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span><span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">contradictions&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span><span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">archaeology&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span><span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">family&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span><span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">hotmail&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(2)</span></span><span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">shocking&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span><span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">baby&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span><span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">big&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span><span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">dd&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span><span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">ff&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span><span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">four&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span><span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">g&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span><span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">job&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span><span class="tag tagHover" data-tag="tag">sss&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:70%;">(1)</span></span>
```

Then to put a bit of space between each element, can be done with some margin settings for each tag element (not shown here).

Not sure why Chrome reacts to the `&nbsp;` at that position differently than the other browsers (wraps fine), but this is what I have found.